# Tab object doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, tabs

Have the following problem:

The dcTabs is not exist anymore in this code.

If I place it outside `if($("#plaats").prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {` it works, but inside not.

```
var dcTabs;

$(document).ready(function () {

// tabs
dcTabs = $('#tabs').tabs({ 
    show: function( event, ui ) { 
    }, 
    select: function( event, ui ) { 
    } 
});


    $('#plaats').change(function() {

            if($("#plaats").prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {

                var tab_count = dcTabs.tabs('length'); 

                for (i=0; i<=tab_count; i++){
                    dcTabs.tabs( "remove" , 0); 
                } 

                dcTabs.tabs("add", "#tabs-kaart", "Kaart");

                $("#tabs-kaart").append('<div id="kaart"></div>');

            }
     }).change(); 
});
```

Comment: Where is dcTabs being defined?

Comment: What do you mean "is not exist anymore"? What happens when you try to run the above, do you get an error message? Also, you are appending a div with a hardcoded id, which means that if your code runs more than once you'll have multiple divs with the same id - which is invalid. If you also (already) have more than one element with the "plaats" id that could explain why that if statement doesn't work...

Comment: @brenjt have change the topic, added where it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/mQuuu/

Comment: I get on alert(dcTabs.tabs('length')); this [object Object] don't understand it anymore :(